# Can I leave Indonesia and use the same visa when I return?

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, indonesia

I have two options to get to Makassar from Padang:

- Padang–Jakarta–Makassar
- Padang–Kuala Lumpur–Makassar

The second one is much cheaper than the first one, but I don't know if I'll have problems when trying to re-enter to Indonesia with my VISA. The two legs of the flight are with Air Asia, but they are different tickets (in fact I'll leave the airport because there's a long layover).

The question is: when I arrive in Makassar, will I have to buy another VISA, or will the one I have still be valid? (Please, assume I have a VISA on arrival; I'm not going to the embassy to get one.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you can't, the Indonesian VOA is a single entry visa valid for one entry for 30 days. I go to Jakarta at least once a month and my passport is full with these, unfortunately even if I come back in less than 30 days I will have to issue a new one for each entry. So, consider an extra $25 VOA fees for the second itinerary.

Official reference: [Directorate General Of Immigration (§3)](http://www.imigrasi.go.id/index.php/en/public-services/visa-for-visitor):

> 3.Visit Visa for **1 (one) time travel** given to Foreigners intending to conduct:
>
> - Tour;
> - ....

Comment: I can confirm that $25 is the current price

Comment: @Ivan yes, still $25, few years ago there was a $10 VOA valid for 10 days.. not any more..